# Mysql. Function ROUND doesn't give right value

Tags: mysql, function, rounding

I have a problema with this select:

```
select @a := 992.7500, ROUND(@a * (1 + 18 / 100), 2) AS Total;
```

As Total it get 1171.44, but its value must be 1171.45. If execute Workbench and I run the same select again, it get the right value.

¿How I can do for obtain the right value? Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That *is* the correct value. It just uses Banker's Rounding per the [spec](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-rounding.html).

> ROUND() uses the following rules depending on the type of the first argument:
>
> For exact-value numbers, ROUND() uses the “round half away from zero”
>   or “round toward nearest” rule: A value with a fractional part of .5
>   or greater is rounded up to the next integer if positive or down to
>   the next integer if negative. (In other words, it is rounded away from
>   zero.) A value with a fractional part less than .5 is rounded down to
>   the next integer if positive or up to the next integer if negative.
>
> For approximate-value numbers, the result depends on the C library. On
>   many systems, this means that ROUND() uses the "round to nearest even"
>   rule: A value with any fractional part is rounded to the nearest even
>   integer.

Banker's rounding, or "round to nearest even" is the preferred rounding method for imprecise numerical values like `double` since it addresses the upward bias of the alternative.

> Bankers Rounding is an algorithm for rounding quantities to integers,
>   in which numbers which are equidistant from the two nearest integers
>   are rounded to the nearest even integer. Thus, 0.5 rounds down to 0;
>   1.5 rounds up to 2.

Comment: Ok. But why the same sentence give diferents results? Try yourself. Run this sentence and when see the result in the screen, run again. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I understand. No more problem. Thanks very much.

Comment: How I can obtain the right with that query with the first run?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `SET` statements, you can obtain the right value with the first run.

```
SET @a = 992.7500;
select ROUND(@a * (1 + 18 / 100), 2) AS Total;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.

> Another issue with assigning a value to a variable and reading the value within the same non-SET statement is that the default result type of a variable is based on its type at the start of the statement.

`@a` is exact-value number when you use `SET`. `@a` assigned in `SELECT` statements seems not to be exact-value but approximate-value numbers.

MySQL 8.0(current) still supports the syntax you wrote, but the syntax is subject to removal in a future release of MySQL.

> Previous releases of MySQL made it possible to assign a value to a user variable in statements other than SET. This functionality is supported in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility but is subject to removal in a future release of MySQL.